# find all overrides of a virtual method using clang

Tags: c++, compilation, llvm

is there a way  to find all overriding  methods of a given method with clang ?
Or even get all derived classes of a given class ?

I could manage myself some kind of inheritance map and populate it while visiting `CXXRecordDecls`,
but maybe there is a simpler way ?  I googled it but didn't find help nowhere .